# How to convert from GSON to JACKSON?

Tags: json, jackson, gson

What is the equivalent of the below class in jackson?

```
public class JsonConverter
{
    private static final JsonConverter INSTANCE = new JsonConverter();
    private Gson gson;

    private JsonConverter() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBilder.registerTypeAdapter(AbstractElement.class, new AbstractElementAdapter());
        gsonBilder.registerTypeAdapter(ClientAction.class, new ClientActionEnumAdapter());
        gsonBilder.serializeNulls();
        gson = gsonBilder.create();
    }

    public static Gson getGson() {
        return INSTANCE.gson;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectMapper` is the equivalent of `Gson`; it is constructed directly without builder.

Configuration settings and style differ, as does registration of custom adapters.